# Constrained optimization with constrOptim: coefficients should sum to 1

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to maximize a loglikelihoodfunction under the constraint that the parameters should sum to 1. For this I thought the constrOptim function to be a good tool. However, running my minimal example below yields an error saying that the initial values are not in the allowed range even though they are equivalent to the values in the data generating process. Can anyone help me and say what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

```
# Generate example data
set.seed(123)
x1 <- rnorm(1000)
x2 <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rbinom(1000, 1, plogis(0.5 + 0.3*x1 + 0.2*x2)) 

# log-likelihood 
logl <- function(theta,x,y){
  y <- y
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  beta <- theta[1:ncol(x)]
  loglik <- sum(-y*log(1 + exp(-(x%*%beta))) - (1-y)*log(1 + exp(x%*%beta)))
  return(-loglik)
}

constrOptim(c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2), logl, x = cbind(1, x1, x2), y = y, hessian = TRUE, method = "L-BFGS-B", control=list(fnscale=1), ui=rbind(rep(1, 3)), ci=c(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sum-to-1 is the only constraint you have, you can try to directly include it in the objective function: Run an unconstrained optimization with only two parameters, and compute the third parameter in your objective function.

```
 logl <- function(theta,x,y){
  y <- y
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  beta <- c(theta, 1-sum(theta))  ## compute third parameter
  loglik <- sum(-y*log(1 + exp(-(x%*%beta))) - (1-y)*log(1 + exp(x%*%beta)))
  return(-loglik)
}

optim(c(0.5, 0.3), fn = logl, x = cbind(1, x1, x2), y = y)
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I did not reduced the problem two two parameters was that I would like to infer the standard error from the Hessian also for the this parameter. Do you have a hint for me how I can achieve also this in this setting here?

Comment: Given all parameters (two from the optimization and one self-computed) you can  approximate numerically the Hessian of the original function. See e.g. package `numDeriv` (`hessian`). There are caveats, such as numerical stability, and in particular the fact that the Hesse matrix would then be of the unconstrained model; but those caveats apply to `constrOptim` as well. (And for standard errors in general, there is always resampling/bootstrapping.)

Comment: Thanks, Enrico. Sounds like I will have to bootstrap my standard errors. Thanks for the hint to the numDeriv package nevertheless.